# jQuery hover slide submenu not working when collapsed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, slidedown, mouseenter, mouseleave

I'm trying to create a navigation menu which implements the slideDown/slideUp function on mouseenter/mouseleave to display a submenu. I only want the slidedown/slideup function to run when the menu is expanded horizontally for large screens. When the hamburger menu is displayed (small screens) I just want the users to have to click on menu items to display the submenu. I've managed to get the sliding functions to work as intended but when the hamburger menu is displayed I can't click on the menu items to display a submenu. Any ideas?

jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.submenu').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {
                    //show subnav on hover
                    $(this).mouseenter(function () {
                        if ($('#navBarCollapseButton').css('display') == 'none')
                        { $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown(); }
                    });
                    //hide submenus on exit
                    $(this).mouseleave(function () {
                        if ($('#navBarCollapseButton').css('display') == 'none')
                        { $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp(); }
                    });

                };
            });
        });
</script>
```

html:

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header" id="navBarHeader">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" id="navBarCollapseButton">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navBar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="menu-item">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li class="submenu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Main1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Item1", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Item2", "About", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="submenu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Main2</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li class="submenu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SubMain1</a>
                            <ul  role="menu">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Item3", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Item4", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("SubMain2", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Home","Index", "Home")
    </footer>
</div>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Update: have been coming back to this periodically over the last couple of weeks and it still has me stumped. Please help!

Comment: please add working fiddle, it will be easy to update your code there..

Comment: Can you provide demo by using fiddle/something that can be reproduced? I think your HTML code represents a layout page which renders together with any view page referenced it.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Sorry it took a while, not used jsfiddle before: https://jsfiddle.net/aprigg11/vatwou3c/

Comment: And yes, you are correct, it is a layout razor file.